# Angular directive passing content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Been trying to get my own autocomplete plugin to work as an Angular directive

Hopefully this is a straightforward one, please let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree with this.

So I have a jquery autocomplete plugin that I wrote myself, just trying to hook it up in Angular as a directive, purely to have a play with my own directives.

The bit I'm struggling with is passing the content of the text box to the api endpoint. If you look in the demo and in the console, you'll see it is passing undefined across each time (line 133 and 173 in jsfiddle).

```
scope.testAutocomplete = new AA('Test', element,{
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonPath: 'http://apiendpoint.com?query=' + scope.searchTerm + '&apikey=1234&limit=5'
```

The 'watch' inside the directive updates correctly, but it passes 'undefined' to the endpoint.

apologies for the fiddle, Plunkr just won't save for some reason.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/PxHC3/7/show/
http://jsfiddle.net/PxHC3/7/

So before I even get to passing info into scopes and such, I'm just wondering if I'm on the right path.

Cheers
Tom

Comment: The line `jsonPath: 'http://apiendpoint.com?query=' + scope.searchTerm + '&apikey=1234&limit=5'` when executes, the value of `scope.searchTerm` is undefined. You need to rebuild `jsonPath` on `searchTerm` change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created a jsonPath variable which I am trying to update on watch. But it just outputs blank: http://fiddle.jshell.net/PxHC3/9/show/

Comment: I'd look at wrapping your autocomplete call in a function and calling it on change, like so: `ng-change="changed(search)"`. Then in your controller / link: `$scope.changed = function(searchTerm){ // do lookup };`